# Custom keyboard zoomed for apps not optimized for iphone 6 & 6+

Tags: iphone, keyboard, ios8, storyboard

I am building a custom keyboard and I find for apps not optimised for iPhone 6 and 6plus the keyboard is zoomed and looks weird. I am building the keyboard using Interface builder with fixed sizes, meaning I dont want it to be zoomed.

How can I detect if the view for the keyboard is optimised for iPhone 6 and 6plus?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't the native keyboard also magnified for apps that are magnified?

Comment: Yes. I found to know if there is a way to avoid this magnification of a custom keyboard.

Comment: In Zoomed Mode the nativeScale and scale will not be the same

Comment: did you find the answer? please let us know